# Regular throughput troughs in Azure functions requests per second

Tags: azure-functions

I am running an Azure function in Consumption Plan mode and am seeing regular troughs in throughput as shown in the attached image. I have stripped out all external dependencies such that function execution is predictable, as in, receive single event from event hub, create a new event hub message, and write back to (source) event hub via IAsyncCollector parameter.

While the behavior is not a problem per se, I am curious as to why it exists and if it is specific to the Consumption Plan mode?

[Consumption Plan function requests per sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o43P.png)

Comment: Does the timeline you show consist of a constant throughput, or are there gaps? Functions booting up for the first time in a while (cold start) do suffer performance hits.

Comment: The timeline is for consistent throughput.

Comment: I recommend filing an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script. This is not expected behavior, and is worth looking into.

Comment: Issue logged: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2242

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Functions product group pointed me to their post https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/19/processing-100000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/

Big thanks for their help and patience.

I have applied some of these and posted my findings :
https://sabin.io/blog/improving-azure-functions-throughput/